# How do I detect a destroyed object in Unity?

Tags: unity, gameobject

I have an object in unity which is spawn through a script. Upon detecting that the object has taken substantial damage, objectDestroy is called and the object is removed.

However, I would like for a message to appear upon having this object destroyed. The code I posted below doesn't work.

```
hudText.Add ("Use Mouse 1 to fire !", Color.red, 2f);

while(trigger==false){
    if(enemy==null){

        Debug.Log ("Gone");

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        hudText.Add ("Nice work!", Color.green, 3f);

        trigger = true;
    }
    Debug.Log (trigger);
    yield return null;
}
```

I suspect that this has to with the fact that the object is destroyed at the end of the frame, but the while loop here never allows the loop to test for the following frame.

How do I do this?

Comment: Do you mean *detecting that an object was destroyed*? As it stands, literally *detecting a destroyed object* would be hard, as the object you're trying to detect would be gone.

Comment: First off, you didn't actually explain the problem you are having; I assume the problem is that everything inside `if(enemy==null){` never happens, but is that the problem? Also, I'm curious what `trigger` means, gonna need more context for that. For example, you show when that value become `true` but when does it become false?

Comment: Ah sorry, my description is a little vague upon inspection. I have updated it.


_Trigger is set to "false" by default. As goes on to the second "if" loop and see if it's criteria is valid. If it is (enemy == null), a message is suppose to display and trigger set to "true" to escape from the while loop._

Comment: and is Debug.Log(trigger) firing?

Comment: Unity overrides the `==` operator such that a destroyed object will always equal `null`. The code as posted is a little clumsy, but should work as a coroutine. Are you sure it's being called at all?

Comment: I've check and turns out the if statement never detects the destroyed object at all. If it helps, the object is destroyed through a javascript file attached to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use two approaches here; directly calling a function when the object is destroyed, or handling an array of objects yourself.

In the first approach, you could take advantage of the [OnDestroy](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnDestroy.html) function that belongs to MonoBehaviour.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class YourClass : MonoBehaviour {
     void OnDestroy() {
         Debug.Log("I'm gone! (bye, bye)");
     }
}
```

And that function gets called when you do something like

```
Destroy(myGameObject);
```

The second approach is similar but it requires a little more work. It always depend on what you're trying to achieve but I'll give you an example

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class YourClass : MonoBehaviour {
     public int energy;
     void Update() {
         if (energy <= 0) {
             // you're comparing against a value you know beforehand
             Debug.Log("Gone! (bye, bye)");
             // this will just 'hide' the game object visually, for example
             gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enable = false;
             // or just go with it as usual
             Destroy(this.gameObject);
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: The object I'm looking to test (if destroyed) is destroyed using a separate javscript file. How would I go about implementing the above methods into my current script?

Comment: Method 1 works just the same. Just add the function to your MonoBehaviour script attached in the game object.

Method 2 need a workaround. Maybe you could have a new function called "CustomDestroy" and then do the proper operations there (really destroying the object or just disabling the visual components)